# Working with custom role in VB.NET win application

Tags: vb.net, custom-attributes, user-roles

I am looking for ways to implement custom user-roles in windows application with vb.net. I got a database table called Roles with Administrator and User entries. User cannot see some of the  form data. In ASP.NET MVC we can do like.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public function GetAccount() as Array

End Function
```

If it could be done this way that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for the ASP.NET Authorize attribute is online [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/network/Show?projectName=aspnet&changeSetId=23011#266447).  You can see how they implemented it in MVC and adapt it to your needs.